# Elevated privileges with specific user/password on Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, uac, credentials, privileges

I'm developing an application to run some default steps my co workers have to do, but i'm the only one which have the admin's password and my app need admin privileges, but i can't log in everytime for them...

I though in create a function to self elevate my program or launch it with the admin credential, but i can't find anything about without passing the user and password as parameters to third part applications, and this can easily tracked.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: Running an app with administrator rights from a non-admin account will *always* prompt for administrative credentials. Most apps that require admin privileges won't accept the credentials from a command line; they simply presume the app is being run by an admin and let Windows handle things.

Comment: Build a service that will handle the admin steps and a client that will trigger the service to do so. Thats how Windows Update and Firefox Updater (and many more) do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

1. use `LogonUser()` to login to the desired user account, then `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` to have the calling thread impersonate that user before performing the desired tasks, and then `RevertToSelf()` when finished to stop impersonating.
2. move the admin tasks to a separate process, and then use `LogonUser()` and `CreateProcessAsUser()`, or alternatively `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`, to launch that process using the user credentials when needed.

Comment: I'm not shure how it works with second option, but Impersonate worked very well. Thanks